# CSS not loading in Firefox, Opera and IE - Chrome and Safari works just fine

Tags: css, firefox, safari, opera

Im having some problems at a website construction, and the point is that in Chrome and Safari it works just fine, but not quite the same in Firefox, Opera and Internet Explorer.

[Check the website here !](http://www.dev.alectryon.pt)

You can try it in the browsers that i mentioned, and confirm what i just said.

Any tips ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey Change to your css type

you define `type="text/javascript"` it's wrong

```
just define type="text/css"
```

---

Now change This

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/javascript" href="estilos/estilos.css">
```

into

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos/estilos.css">
```

Comment: It was a lack of attention. Things like this just happens.
Thank you very much !