# Css not loading in IE,Firefox,Opera and working fine with Chrome and Safari

Tags: javascript, css

On my site http://www.mazishi.com/index.php/component/obituary/detail/11.html#tabs-2 Css is loading fine in Chrome and Safari... I don't know whats going wrong with IE, FireFox and Opera.

I have check the ref link [CSS not loading in Firefox, Opera and IE - Chrome and Safari works just fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10846868/css-not-loading-in-firefox-opera-and-ie-chrome-and-safari-works-just-fine...but) that didn't work.

Any Help will be appreciated,
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS file is loading fine but looks there are some error in your CSS code like unclosed strings,

`[12:07:25.080] Found unclosed string '"}.hasTip{cursor:pointer}.add{cursor:pointer}.comment_status{cursor:pointer}..fb_iframe_widget{display:block}.comment_trash{cursor:pointer}.asset_icon{clear:both}.asset_icon'.  Expected declaration but found '"}.hasTip{cursor:pointer}.add{cursor:pointer}.comment_status{cursor:pointer}..fb_iframe_widget{display:block}.comment_trash{cursor:pointer}.asset_icon{clear:both}.asset_icon'.  Skipped to next declaration. @ http://www.mazishi.com/cache/helix_assets/cf9b9e5033a9adee8f2ffb8a7841259a.css:440`

You can check your CSS errors using w3validator, http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mazishi.com%2Fcache%2Fhelix_assets%2Fcf9b9e5033a9adee8f2ffb8a7841259a.css&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en

Fix the errors and it will fix your problems.